# css spacing in span for error message

Tags: html, css

I have the below jsfiddle I need to know how should I increase the space for error message in span so that the entire message is displayed correctly.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fakhruddin/Fg3zP/)

```
    <form method="post" action="" id="subscribeForm" name="subscribeForm">
        <fieldset>
            <label>Name: </label><input type="text" class="effect" name="name" id="name"  autocomplete="off" >
            <span id="nameInfo">What's your name?</span>
        </fieldset>

        <fieldset>
            <label>Email: </label><input type="text" class="effect" name="email" id="email"  autocomplete="off" >
            <span id="emailInfo">Valid E-mail please, you will need it to log in!</span>
        </fieldset>

        <div id="button">
            <input type="submit" value="Subscribe" name="subscribeForm"/>
        </div>
        <div id="success">
            <strong>Data Saved Successfully.</strong>
        </div>
    </form>
```

CSS Code

```
    #subscribeForm span.error{
                color: #e46c6e;
            }

            #subscribeForm input.error{
                background: #f8dbdb;
                border-color: #e77776;
            }

            #subscribeForm span.error{
                color: #e46c6e;
            }

            #subscribeForm span{
                margin-left: 50px;
                color: #b1b1b1;
                font-size: 11px;
                font-style: italic;
            }
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fakhruddin/Fg3zP/)

Comment: Please suggest me some improvements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try increasing the height of the fieldset.

```
fieldset {
        overflow:hidden;
        border:0;
        height:50px;    
        margin:3px 0;
    }
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/acFmN/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Increasing the width of the fieldset or the form will display the error text fully. 
So try,

```
form {
  ...
  width: 285px;
  ...
}
```

if you do not want to display bigger form try to set the width of fieldset alone like,

```
fieldset {
  ...
  width: 270px;
  ...
}
```

Check the demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Fg3zP/5/)
, i have set the width of the fieldset here, form size is not changed.